# How to keep old values during mysql LOAD DATA?

Tags: mysql, sql, loaddata

I'm using the following to batch insert `csv` data to a `mysql` table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' REPLACE into table persons 
      (firstname, lastname, age)
```

persons.csv:

```
#first,last,age
john,doe,32
jane,done,22
```

database table:

```
firstname, lastname, age, birthday
```

Question: how can I replace existing rows, but KEEP the `birthday` row if already set?

I using as above, the `birthday` row will always contain `NULL` values, no matter if a value existed in that field before insertion.

Comment: You can create a data copy in a temp table & then after import you can update birthday from temp table.

Comment: so there is no chance I could achieve this using `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: Is there any unique key into the table?

Comment: You can also review https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771546/6318514

Comment: there is no single unique key in the table, but a composite primary key constraint.