# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - INSERT OR UPDATE DEPENDING ON A COLUMN

Tags: mysql

I am using this query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Base.txt' INTO TABLE my_data 
CHARACTER SET latin1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

To insert the data into the my_data table works great, the problem is how to implement the following with the LOAD DATA MYSQL QUERY.

**Condition 1:**
IF the column SKU in the CSV file MATCHES with the column SKU in the my_data table
THEN
UPDATE column NEW_FLAG=1 in the database.

**Condition 2:**
IF the column SKU in the CSV file DOES NOT MATCH with the column SKU in the my_data table
THEN
INSERT the records as it is.

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801302/trying-to-do-load-data-infile-with-replace-and-auto-increment